# Unity C#; What's the reason of Resources.load(PNG file path) always return null?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to change the image that clicked image button.
so, I set a button and try to load a PNG file at assets/Resources/ PATH.
But it always return and it makes me massed up -_-.
Some of questions likes my situation, everybody answers 'try to move file to load assets/Resoucres PATH and my situation couldn't be fixed that way.

Here is my code. This function is load a NumCard_1.png file when clicked a image button. NumCard_1.png exists at assets/Resources folder.

```
void OnclkMe()
{
    Sprite newSprite = Resources.Load<Sprite>("/NumCard_1") as Sprite;
    // I already try ("NumCard_1") instead above.
    if(newSprite==null)
    {
        Debug.Log("NULL");    // Always prints "NULL" -_-.
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log(newSprite.name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try like that: `Sprite newSprite = Resources.Load<Sprite>("NumCard_1") as Sprite;`

Comment: The Load function basically treats any Resources folder in your assets as possible relative path, so you don't put a `/` at the front of the string. If it is directly in a resources folder, just use the name of the file, otherwise something like `SubFolder/NumCard_1`.

Comment: You don't need the 'as Sprite' if you're using the generic version of Load.

Answer (score 3):

When using Resources.Load in Unity, it uses a relative folder to "Resources"
every resource you intend to use at runtime must be located under /Resources, if it ain't there - create it.
after you create this base folder (under Assets) you can create subfolders by your own preference.

secondly, Resources.Load("/NumCard_1") as Sprite is kind of misused.
the generic method Resources.Load returns T so you can drop the "as Sprite" (it will act the same).

as Unity uses "Resources" as base folder you should remove the "/" before "NumCard".
if you use subfolder you might want to specify the path as "Cards/NumCard_1".

as per your code, after creating the folder Assets/Resources and placing the img in it, try the following:

```
Sprite newSprite = Resources.Load<Sprite>("NumCard_1")
```

Comment: Just to emphasize: it doesn't matter where your resources folder is in the assets and how many you have. You can have `Assets/Textures/Resources` + `Assets/Resources/Materials` + `Resources/Meshes/Resources` and this will work perfectly fine. A logical approach for the folder structure is obviously advised.

Answer (score 0):

Add your sprite in resources folder.
Change texture type to Sprite, and apply.

Sprite newSprite = Resources.Load("NumCard_1",typeof(Sprite)) as Sprite;

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you don't set import config of that file into sprite? Normally png would be imported as texture, not sprite

First you should try to check it like this

```
var obj = Resources.Load("NumCard_1");
Debug.Log(typeof(obj));
```

If obj is not null, it would tell you what type it is. If it not sprite you would need to go to unity editor, select file, and change import type that png into sprite

ps Using generic mean you can just write is like this

```
var obj = Resources.Load<Sprite>("NumCard_1");
```

And obj will be sprite. If it not a sprite it would be null

Comment: typeof(obj) was an error. 'obj' is a variable, but used like type.

Comment: @김보근 Sorry it `Debug.Log(obj.GetType());`

Comment: But It's very helpful. When I use breakpoint to that, it gave me obj type is Texture2D. Can I convert this type Texture2D to UISprite ? I using NGUI.

Comment: @김보근I don't know how to use NGUI but it mostly need to be done in unity editor, not in the code. Maybe you need to create UISprite prefab and add that texture into it

Comment: Because I want to change an image of ImageButton when it clicked. So I think it must be done in a c# script. And I load NumCard_01.png successful. But How can I change an image of imagebutton. GameObject.GetComponent<T> using, but it doesn't work.

Comment: @김보근 Then maybe you need to look at UISprite component and see is it can change texture somewhere. But still I think UI system like NGUI should have a setting in editor to let you select difference texture for each button state

Answer (score -2):

Folder Name Must be named "Resourses" in asset